# Бан по IP не работает

Tags: ip, php, mysql

Написал простейший скрипт бана пользователя по IP с использованием базы данных, но он почему то не хочет работать. В чем может быть проблема?

```
$myip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bans WHERE ip = '$myip' AND DATEDIFF(startban, endban) < 0";

$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0)

   echo "Вы забанены";
```

До этого идет обычная форма и обработчик полей начальной даты бана, даты конца бана и IP-адрес.
startban и endban это поля в базе данных начала и конца бана соответственно (дата в формате d.m.Y H:i:s)

Comment: Почему такое странное условие? Функция `DATEDIFF` возвращает разницу между датами начала и конца бана, не думаю, что это то, что вам нужно. По-моему, логичнее было бы проверять, входит ли текущая дата в этот интервал.

Comment: >(дата в формате d.m.Y H:i:s)

Ужасно! Ну если в таком виде хранится, сочувствую\+ наверное еще и поле в mysql в виде varchar.

Comment: fori1ton, вот так? Вроде работает

$date = date("d.m.Y H:i:s");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM bans WHERE ip = '$myip' AND ('$date' > startban AND '$date' < endban)";

Shrek, ага :( Я еще начинающий, важно было просто написать рабочий скрипт. А какой тип поля посоветуете под такой формат даты?

Comment: @ChesteR ты смеешься?

Для поля даты и времени есть тип datetime.

Почитай про типы данных в MySql

Comment: Там просто целая группа полей DATE and TIME, вот я и спросил.

Comment: что мешает выбрать нужный тип?

Comment: В принципе ничего. Была небольшая ошибка из-за невнимательности, сейчас все исправил, все вроде-бы работает. Извиняюсь за столь глупые вопросы.